# How can I extract news about a particular company from various websites using RODBC package in R? And perform sentiment analysis on the data?

Tags: r, text-mining, sentiment-analysis

I would like to extract news about a company from online news by using the RODBC package in R. I would then like to use the extracted data for sentiment analysis. I want to accomplish this in such a way that the positive news is assigned a value of +1, the negative news is assigned a value of -1, and the neutral news is assigned a value of 0.

Comment: RODBC is for connecting to relational databases - often ones that are on your premises. You question alludes to  connecting to public API - that is something else.

Comment: You're asking two questions. Please post them separately. You'd better flesh out the part that comes before sentiment analysis too.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a question with a simple answer, so all I can really do is point you in the right direction.

The RODBC package isn't meant to extract data online, it's meant to pull data from a database.  If you will be leveraging that package, it will be after you pull data down from the web.

Jeffrey Bean put together a [slideshow tutorial](http://jeffreybreen.wordpress.com/2011/07/04/twitter-text-mining-r-slides/) for doing sentiment analysis with Twitter data a few years back.  He used the Twitter stream as well as some data pulled in from web scraping.  It's a good starting point.

There's also this site that discusses a few different approaches to this problem in detail, including Bean's, the sentiment package, and ViralHeat (which is a commercial sentiment analysis service who's data you can pull into R).  Sentiment has since been removed ([archived versions here](http://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/sentiment/)), but the [qdap package](http://cran.us.r-project.org/web/packages/qdap/index.html) is available and is designed for use in transcript analysis.